# Evaluate with numbers from list

Tags: equation-solving, evaluation

This code works:

```
x=2
y/.Solve[y==x^2]
Out[138]= 2
Out[139]= {4}
```

So above I put number in variable `x` and getting the result of corresponding `y`

Now I want to give list with several values in list in variable `x` and get evaluated values of corresponding `y`'s. How can I do that?

I tried this but it does not works:

```
x={1,2,3,4}
y/.Solve[y==x^2]
Out[140]= {1,2,3,4}
Out[141]= y
```

Expected output is:

```
{1,4,9,16}
```

Comment: `Solve` needs the variable you're solving for in the second argument, and you want to solve for the array - `Array[y, 4]/.First[Solve[Array[y, 4] == x^2, Array[y, 4]]]`. But obviously you can just do `{1,2,3,4}^2`

Comment: @flinty This does not works: `x = {1, 2, 3, 4}
y /. Solve[Array[y, 4] == x^2, Array[y, 4]]`. How can I fix it?

Comment: What doesn't work? It works perfectly fine for me - you need a semicolon after your first list.

Comment: @flinty You are right. Thank you very much. My mistake!

Comment: You also need `Array[y, 4]/.` not `y/.`

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the following codes:

```
x = {1, 2, 3, 4};Solve[y == z^2] /. z -> x
```

The final result is：

```
{{y -> {1, 4, 9, 16}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not bypass `Solve`, and apply the square directly:

```
x={1, 2, 3, 4};

y = x^2

{1, 4, 9, 16}
```

More complicated operations:

```
y= somethingComplicated[#]&/@x
```

Comment: Thank you. I need a way to use `x={1, 2, 3, 4}` in `y/.Solve[y==x^2]` .

Comment: If bypassing `Solve`, you only need `x = {1, 2, 3, 4}; y = x^2` since `Power` is `Listable`